# how do i initialize the stack using linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

How do I initialize the stack using the linked list with this statement?

Hi, I'm new to IT world. I'm having a problem on how to start this code. We are only given with this structure:

```
typedef struct cell{
   char elem;
   struct cell * next;
}*Stack;
```

we we're told to do the push, pop, top, initialize, empty and full.
As I was doing the INITIALIZE function, I was having a hard time since i am not used to the data type which is the "*Stack".

can anybody help me with this.

Comment: Please tag this with a language (C/C++)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Stack Data Structure and Implementing it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755068/understanding-stack-data-structure-and-implementing-it)

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, you should follow this steps:

1 - [Learn data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure)

2 - [Learn about stack and basic operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Structures/Stacks_and_Queues)

3 - [Learn pointers in C](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm)

4 - [Learn Abstract Data Types in C](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~selfpace/studyguide/9C.sg/Output/ADTs.in.C.html)

After this, build your Abstract Data Type using this Stack example and then code the basic operations: Push and Pop.